# iOS Metal shader language how to flip order of values inside float2?

Tags: c++, metal, ios14

If I have a struct in the metal shader language:

**How do I access individual struct (like `float2`) elements and flip their order?**

```
const float2 sampledCameraPoint = cameraSamplePatternBuffer[vertexID]; // (has x and y)
const float2 flipped = float2(?, ?) // how to get (sampledCameraPoint.y, sampledCameraPoint.x)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the elements using `x`, `y` etc, so this should work:

```
float2 flipped = otherFloat2.yx;
```